# How to show all products affected by a catalog price rule in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a page which shows all products affected by a catalog price rule since these products are on sale at the moment they receive a catalog price rule. Currently I have a piece of code which can show me products from one catalog price rule:

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(12);  /* catalog price rule id */
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
$productIdsArray = $rule->getMatchingProductIds(); 
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection() 
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*") 
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $productIdsArray));
```

I would like to expand this piece of code so I receive all catalog price rules and show all products on sale on a page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have 0 experience with Magento but here is my suggestion.

Can you put this code into a loop which loops through all the catalog price rules id's and then add the products to one general productsCollection?